# How can I get the definition of a function from CodeFunction?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions, envdte, visual-studio-sdk

I do have a CodeFunction object from EnvDTE namespace. I do want to get the definition of it; e.g.:

```
private void MenuItemCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Try");
}
```

I would like to get first line as string.

What I have tried until now,

1 ) Try to make a string by getting CodeFunction's Type (return type) and Parameters then in a loop add them to a string. However, parameter types' names become like "System.UInt32" etc. which I don't want to. Also a problem with this, it may not take `ref Guid pguidCmdGroup` as fully. I am afraid of skipping ref at this.

2 ) I tried to use functions of CodeFunction but all I could get was simple name of it.

3 ) I tried to write from starting point and ending point of the CodeFunction but couldn't find a way to turn two TextPoint to string and as I realized ending point is not the ending of the definition but the function it self which I don't want to.

How can I get just simply `private void MenuItemCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)` or `MenuItemCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)`?

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this is not possible. During compilation, the `string` code is translated to machine-language.

Comment: Maybe but there are some extensions that can edit/search/etc. on editor or active document so isn't there a way to get the definition of method?

Answer (score 1):

You must use *GetStartPoint()* and *GetEndPoint()* :
Read the full source of the function and then cut off the 
code before the first open curly brace.

```
// Retrieve the source code for the function.
TextPoint start = codeFunction.GetStartPoint(vsCMPart.vsCMPartHeader);
TextPoint finish = codeFunction.GetEndPoint();

string fullSource = start.CreateEditPoint().GetText(finish);

// Find the first open curly brace
int openCurlyBracePos = fullSource.IndexOf('{');

string declaration = String.Empty;
if (openCurlyBracePos > -1) {
    declaration = fullSource.Substring(0, openCurlyBracePos).Trim();
}
```